# h5py selective read in

Tags: numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have a problem regarding a selective read-in routine while using h5py.

```
f = h5py.File('file.hdf5','r')
data = f['Data']
```

I have several positive values in the 'Data'- dataset and also some placeholders with -9999.
How I can get only all positive values for calculations like `np.min`?

np.ma.masked_array creates a full copy of the array and all the benefits from using h5py are lost ... (regarding memory usage). The problem is, that I get errors if I try to read data sets that exceed 100 millions of values per data set using `data = f['Data'][:,0]`

Or if this is not possible is something like that possible?

```
np.place(data[...], data[...] <= -9999, float('nan'))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked out pytables? Unlike h5py, it can do some in-place operations on hdf5 files, so it might be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
mask = f['Data'] >= 0
data = f['Data'][mask]
```

although I am not sure how much memory the mask calculation itself uses.